# I can not get values of char array in C

Tags: c, char, arrays

in a.c

```
char write[500][255];

void func1()
{
 int i=0;

 while(i<100)
 {
  char text[255];
  sprintf(text, "abcdefgh %d - %d - %d", i, i*2, i*3);
  strcpy(write[i],text);
  i++;
 }
 func2(&write); 
}
```

in b.c

```
void func2(char *write)
{
 int i=0;

 while(i<100)
 {
  printf("%d --> %s", i, &write[i]);
  i++;
 }
}
```

Result is:

abcdefgh 0 - 0 - 0
bcdefgh 0 - 0 - 0
cdefgh 0 - 0 - 0
defgh 0 - 0 - 0
efgh 0 - 0 - 0
fgh 0 - 0 - 0
gh 0 - 0 - 0
...

and also I get this warning for `func2(&write);`

```
passing argument 1 of 'func2' from incompatible pointer
```

I do not undestand why result is like this. And how can I get rid of this warning.
I can not get values of write[] array. How can I do that?

Thanks

---

Working code is here: http://ideone.com/HTyZwH

Comment: This should not have compiled, because `i++` line is missing a semicolon.

Comment: copy-paste mistake. I edited.

Comment: after you fix that you need to fix segmentation fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the signature of `func2` to:

```
void func2(char write[][255])
```

Note that I don't believe the code posted for `func2` is actually producing the output. Given this line:

```
printf("%d --> %s", i, write[i]);
```

Assuming the compiler gets passed the fact you are converting a 2 dimensional `char` array to a `char*`, specifying `%s` in the format string should cause `printf` to treat the character stored at `write[i]` as a pointer to a string and invoke undefined behavior. Probably a crash.

If the line instead was:

```
printf("%d --> %s", i, &write[i]);
```

Then I could see the output you've shown being produced.